# How do I change innerHTML of loaded page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my jquery to change text inside blocks with class "ToChange". It works fine inside current html file, but it does not with external html file (that I insert with "load" method). Here is my code:

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Home page</title>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script> 
   $(function(){
      $('.insert_external').load("external.html"); 
   });
</script>
<script> 
    $(function(){
        length = document.getElementsByClassName("ToChange").length;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("ToChange")[i].innerHTML = "New Text";
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="insert_external"></div>

<div class="ToChange">
    This changes fine
</div>
<div class="ToChange">
    This changes fine too
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**external.html :**

```
<div class="ToChange">
    This text does not change :(
</div>
```

**As result I see 3 strings :**

> This text does not change :(
>
> New Text
>
> New Text

And I want all of them to be "New Text". Is it possible to do so using only html and js with jquery?

Comment: Javascript works asynchronous. Your replace function will be finished before your load function, so it will show the old text. Use the `complete` callback of the `.load()` function to run your function (again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the html inside `load()` callback so the new data is here, else it will change in the old DOM since the JS works asynchronously.

You've to wait for the `.load()` to finish the request :

```
$('.insert_external').load("external.html", function() {
    length = document.getElementsByClassName("ToChange").length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("ToChange")[i].innerHTML = "New Text";
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** Since you're using jQuery it'll be better to use `.each()` function instead :

```
$('.insert_external').load("external.html", function() {
    $(".ToChange").each(function(){
        $(this).text("New Text");
    })
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. By the way note about '.each' function was also really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The function updating the text is running before the new content is actually loaded, because the load-function works asynchronously. You should wait until the new data has loaded. For this, use the callback of the .load()-function.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
<script> 
   $(function(){
      $('.insert_external').load("external.html",function(){
           setText();
   }); 
   });
</script>

<script> 
    $(function(){
        function setText(){
           length = document.getElementsByClassName("ToChange").length;
           for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
               document.getElementsByClassName("ToChange")[i].innerHTML = "New Text";
           }
        }
    });
</script>
```

You just have to set a callback function when completed.